# Set Pre and Post image about Field Date time to fields Text

Tags: c#, plugins, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-365-v9

I have Field in `DateTime` type and I want to set it's value in images in Plugins set the value in Pre image and after update set the updated value in Post image.

The mother form field type `DateTime` and the child form contains 2 fields (old value field type Text string and the second field new value Type Text string )

```
if (customerDataPreImage.Contains("ph_releasedate"))
{
     customerHistory["ph_oldreleasedate"] = Convert.ToDateTime(customerDataPreImage.Attributes["ph_releasedate"]);
}
if (customerDataPostImage.Contains("ph_releasedate"))
{
     customerHistory["ph_newreleasedate"] = Convert.ToDateTime(customerDataPostImage.Attributes["ph_releasedate"]);
}
```

Comment: An error occurred in the Plugin.System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault]: Incorrect type of attribute value System.DateTime (Fault Detail is equal to Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after change field type to datetime and use this code working fine now

```
if (customerDataPreImage.Contains("ph_releasedate")) {
    customerHistory["ph_oldreleasedate2"] = customerDataPreImage.Attributes["ph_releasedate"];
}
if (customerDataPostImage.Contains("ph_releasedate")) {
    customerHistory["ph_newreleasedate2"] = customerDataPostImage.Attributes["ph_releasedate"];
}
```